# DateTime TextBox is not empty, how to get current date

Tags: c#, jquery, html, datetime

I have two "Html.TextBoxFor" which is linked to an model field (Strongly typed). On page load it shows the value 0001-01-01 00:00:00 in the textbox. I want to get the current date in the format "dd-MM-yyyy" and put it into the textbox. So the date 08-09-2015 should be seen when you load the page.

To do that I need to change format. What I have tried so far, is to add this line of code:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

over the fields in my model. This actually works, but on page load the textbox still have **"0001-01-01 00:00:00"**, and not **"0001-01-01"**

Also to get the current date, is the best method to use Jquery?

**Some code of the textboxes**

```
 <label>Departure date</label>
 <br />
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { @class = "textbox" })
 <label>Return date</label>
 <br />
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnDate, new { @class = "textbox" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Way 1:

You have to do like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { 
                                             Value=Model.DepartureDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : Model.DepartureDate  ,
                                             @class = "textbox" 
                                           })
```

### Way 2:

or alternatively you can do it in get of your Model property:

```
private DateTime _departureDate
public DateTime DepartureDate
{
  get
  {
     return _departureDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : _departureDate; 

  }

  set
  {
    _departureDate = value;
  }
}
```

and then you don't need to use `Value` attribute now, you have to write same as in your OP:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { @class = "textbox" })
```

Comment: is there a way i can add +1 day to the current day? if i want to day after the current day?

Comment: @Mikkel yes you can call ``AddDays(1)`` after ``DateTime.Now`` like: ``DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)``

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery is also a good solution.It will enrich UI at the same time.

With jQuery code will be like this,

```
<label>Departure date</label>
<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { @class = "textbox",@id="datepicker" })
<label>Return date</label>
<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnDate, new { @class = "textbox" })
```

Add following script and style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {  
$("#datepicker").datepicker(); 
$("#ReturnDate").datepicker();  
});
</script>
```

The Razor View Engine by default create an id for TextBox Editor as model attribute name. That's why

```
 $("#ReturnDate").datepicker();
```

also will work. 
Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value for Date along with model from controller DateTime.Now.